# Django Channels ws url not connecting when page loads

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm trying to setup django channels with the following code

## consumery.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

## routing.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from consumers import ChatConsumer

#supposed to be on the main routing
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/$', ChatConsumer),
]

#after linking to above as chat.routing
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

## settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'chatsys.routing.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'channels',
]
```

## script.js

```
//Sockets
var myWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/chat/");

myWebSocket.onopen = function(evt) { 
    alert("Connection open ..."); 
};

myWebSocket.onmessage = function(evt) { 
    alert( "Received Message: " + evt.data); 
};

myWebSocket.onclose = function(evt) { 
    alert("Connection closed."); 
};    

// Call onopen directly if socket is already open
if (myWebSocket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) myWebSocket.onopen(); 
//End Sockets
```

That's the entirety of the whole code. The script is loaded on the homepage and expects to connect to the ws `/chat/` url but instead throws the alert `alert("Connection closed.");` as soon as the page loads so the connection never completes.

Diagnosis where the bug is, is also not as easy since Channels is still relatively new and changing.

## Debugging

```
new WebSocket("ws://35.185.80.98/chat/")
WebSocket { url: "ws://35.185.80.98/chat/", readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, onclose: null, extensions: "", protocol: "", onmessage: null, binaryType: "blob" }
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://35.185.80.98/chat/.
```

Comment: why `new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/chat/");` and why not `new WebSocket("ws://localhost:portnumber/chat/");`?

Comment: because it's running on a server and the IP might change

Comment: @Adelin port number? Hmmm does channels have a port number?

Comment: yes, and from config I might be wrong but looks like it's using a port number `"hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],`

Comment: it runs on `6379` but isn't that just for the backend not the port to connect to

Comment: tried that but get the same message on the console `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://35.185.80.98/chat/.`

Comment: Where's the port number? In the message it doesn't look like a port number was used

Comment: Can you verify that it enters `connect` consumer successfully? Can you print something in connect function and check?

Comment: I undid the port so it also returned the same message plus the port ... `var myWebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + ":6379/chat/");`

Comment: Advice, for debugging purposes, open developer console of Firefox and write there `new WebSocket("ws://35.185.80.98:6379/chat/")`

Comment: @Adelin updated the question to include the results of the test

Comment: I apologize - I had outdated comment - use the port as well